# Genymotion not working with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, genymotion

Whenever I try to use a Genymotion emulator in Visual Studio, It looks like it is about to deploy then I get the following message:

```
08-28 14:55:10.532 D/dalvikvm( 2435): Late-enabling CheckJNI
08-28 14:55:12.804 I/ActivityThread( 2435): Pub com.companyname.app1.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
08-28 14:55:12.820 D/dalvikvm( 2435): GC_CONCURRENT freed 155K, 3% free 10981K/11271K, paused 104ms+1ms, total 193ms
08-28 14:55:12.824 D/dalvikvm( 2435): DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.splitPublicSourceDirs
08-28 14:55:12.836 W/dalvikvm( 2435): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 156
08-28 14:55:12.836 D/dalvikvm( 2435): VFY: replacing opcode 0x54 at 0x0019
08-28 14:55:12.948 D/dalvikvm( 2435): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.companyname.app1/lib/libxamarin-app.so 0xa6ce46f0
08-28 14:55:12.952 D/dalvikvm( 2435): Added shared lib /data/data/com.companyname.app1/lib/libxamarin-app.so 0xa6ce46f0
08-28 14:55:12.972 D/dalvikvm( 2435): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.companyname.app1/lib/libxamarin-app.so 0xa6ce46f0, skipping init
08-28 14:55:12.976 D/dalvikvm( 2435): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.companyname.app1/lib/libmonodroid.so 0xa6ce46f0
08-28 14:55:13.048 D/dalvikvm( 2435): Added shared lib /data/data/com.companyname.app1/lib/libmonodroid.so 0xa6ce46f0
08-28 14:55:13.120 W/monodroid( 2435): Creating public update directory: `/data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__`
08-28 14:55:13.176 W/monodroid( 2435): Using override path: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__
08-28 14:55:13.176 W/monodroid( 2435): Using override path: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__
08-28 14:55:13.188 W/monodroid( 2435): Using runtime path: /data/data/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/lib
08-28 14:55:13.188 W/monodroid( 2435): checking directory: `/data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
08-28 14:55:13.188 W/monodroid( 2435): directory does not exist: `/data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
08-28 14:55:13.192 W/monodroid( 2435): checking directory: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
08-28 14:55:13.216 W/monodroid( 2435): directory does not exist: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
08-28 14:55:13.252 W/monodroid( 2435): checking directory: `/mnt/sdcard/../legacy/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
08-28 14:55:13.252 W/monodroid( 2435): directory does not exist: `/mnt/sdcard/../legacy/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/lib`
08-28 14:55:13.260 W/monodroid( 2435): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
08-28 14:55:13.276 W/monodroid( 2435): Trying to load sgen from: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
08-28 14:55:13.300 W/monodroid( 2435): Trying to load sgen from: /mnt/sdcard/../legacy/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
08-28 14:55:13.300 W/monodroid( 2435): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
08-28 14:55:13.412 W/monodroid( 2435): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/links/libmonosgen-2.0.so
08-28 14:55:13.788 W/monodroid-debug( 2435): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:29206,server=y,embedding=1
08-28 14:55:13.824 W/monodroid-debug( 2435): Accepted stdout connection: 38
08-28 14:55:13.860 W/monodroid( 2435): directory does not exist: `/data/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/typemaps`
08-28 14:55:13.864 W/monodroid( 2435): directory does not exist: `/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.companyname.app1/files/.__override__/typemaps`
Could not connect to the debugger.
```

I am using an AMD processor with Hyper V. I've heard that Genymotion is the quickest emulator with AMD so I am not sure why it doesn't work no matter what emulator I use.

Comment: You can use the default emulator in Visual Studio: [android-emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use another emulator rather to struggle with this one. Personally I am using MEmu to test my apps and its working fine with visual studio. Nox app player was also doing its job.